# How large must $n$ be to have $P[X \geq 1] = 0.99$ when $p = 0.95$?

Tags: probability-distributions, statistical-inference, binomial-distribution

certain type of weapon has probability $p$ of working successfully. We test $n$ weapons, and the stockpile is replaced if the number of failures, $X$, is at least one. How large must $n$ be to have $P[X \geq 1] = 0.99$ when $p = 0.95$?

I only have one question about this exercise: is it advisable to use the central limit theorem to find $n$ or is it better to use other results, such as Chebyshov's inequality, for example?
Any good suggestion is important.

Comment: You really want the probability to be **exactly** $0.99$, not $\ge0.99$? Are you sure?

Answer (score 0):

(assuming independence)

EDIT: as note by @bof (thanks for correcting) I confused successes with failures.

Using the binomial, the question is to calculate

$$\mathbb{P}[X \geq 1]=1-\mathbb{P}[X =0]$$

Where X are the failures in a binomial $B(n;0.95)$

That is

$$1-\binom{n}{n}0.95^n\cdot 0.05^0=1-0.95^n$$

Now simply setting

$$1-0.95^n\geq 0.99$$

you get

$$n\geq \Bigg\lceil\frac{log0.01}{log0.95}\Bigg\rceil=90$$

Comment: $X$ is the number of failures and $p$ is the probability of success, so I think $P[X=0]=p^n=0.95^n$. Anyway, OP asked for $P[X\ge1]=0.99$, not $P[X\ge1]\ge0.99$, so I think there is no solution.

Comment: @tommik  There are two things I don't understand: why do you say that $P(X \geq 1) = 1 - P(X=0)$ (I know that $P(X\geq x) = 1-P(X \leq x)$) and why $P(X=0)=p^n$? On the other hand, are you considering $X$ with a binomial distribution?

Comment: @JhöśëElijäh : I confused successes with failures...now I edited my answer

Comment: @bof : thanks for correcting.

Comment: @tommik 
I know that if $X$ has a binomial distribution, then its pdf is $\mathbb{P}[X=x]= f(x) = \binom{n}{x}p^{x}(1-p)^{n-x}$, $1 \leq p \leq 1$. So I don't understand why you say that $\mathbb{P}[X=0] = \binom{n}{n}0.95^n\cdot 0.05^0=0.95^n$. Can you explain this part please.